# Trying to Convert SQL query to SQLAlchemy query

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to translate raw SQL into an sqlalchemy query, but so far I'm getting different results. The results I get from my attempt at sqlalchemy is missing Property objects (I get back a tuple with (ListingCalendarDays, None, PricingData)), so I think something is missing in the translation.

Original query:

```
   result = session.execute("""SELECT p.id as property_id,
           p.home_code,
           c.listing_id,
           c.calendar_date,
           c.available,
           ab.price
        FROM listing_calendar_days c
        LEFT JOIN properties p
            ON (p.id::integer = c.listing_id and p.id is not null and p.id <> '')
        LEFT JOIN pricing_data ab
            ON c.listing_id = ab.listing_id
            AND c.calendar_date = ab.price_date
        WHERE c.calendar_date >= '%s'
        AND c.calendar_date <= '%s' ;""" % ( now.isoformat(), end.isoformat()))
```

My Attempt:

```
query = (session.query( ListingCalendarDays, Properties, PricingData )
            .outerjoin(Properties,
                and_(Properties.id == str(ListingCalendarDays.listing_id),
                     Properties.id != None))
            .outerjoin(PricingData,
                and_(ListingCalendarDays.listing_id == PricingData.listing_id,
                     ListingCalendarDays.calendar_date == PricingData.price_date))
            .filter(ListingCalendarDays.calendar_date.between( now, end )))

result = query.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print out the query that SQLAlchemy generates by doing

```
print(query)
```

In this particular case, your join condition for `Properties` is wrong. `str(ListingCalendarDays.listing_id)` produces the literal string `"ListingCalendarDays.listing_id"`, not the column `listing_id` as casted to `varchar`. For a cast, you need the [`cast()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.cast) construct:

```
cast(ListingCalendarDays.listing_id, String)
```

In addition, you're also missing the `p.id <> ''` condition.

Putting it all together:

```
and_(Properties.id == cast(ListingCalendarDays.listing_id, String),
     Properties.id != None,
     Properties.id != "")
```